# Python program to read Excel files and copy their sqls into new text file

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am very new to Python, need some help.

I am using Python 3.6.1. I am working on creating a Python script which will read all the Excel (.xlsx) files from a folder. In those files, it should search for files which contain a SQL tab as worksheet and then it should copy the A2 column from the SQL tab of the worksheet and create a .sql with same name as the Excel file appended to it. 
Till now I am able to read all the .xlsx files from the folder, look if they have a SQL tab and then copy the A2 column. Can someone please help me in guiding on how I can create a .sql file and copy the sql of all the Excel files to these .sql files with the Excel name appended to the .sql files.

Following is where I am right now,

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import walk
from openpyxl import load_workbook

cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\Data_Dumps\New folder")])

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk(r'C:\Users\Data_Dumps\New folder'):
    print('Total Files in the folder are: %d' %cpt)
    print('Total filenames are') 
    print(filenames)

files = os.listdir(dirpath)
print(files)
files_xls = [f for f in filenames if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
print('Excel files are:')
print(files_xls)

#Creating data frame to store SQL
df = pd.DataFrame()

files_xls_string = '\n'.join(files_xls)
df = df.append(files_xls_string)

wb = load_workbook(files_xls_string, read_only=True)
if 'SQL' in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SQL')
    SQL = sheet['A2'].value
```

> **Note to @Shams**: This is a SQL SELECT statement, where are your **data**?
>   A2 value eg:

```
select ip.item_code , ip.gla_code_ar ,r.ruleit_text LCSPAINTSZ from item i , itemplant ip , ruleit r where i.item_code = ip.item_code and ip.plant_code = '14' and i.item_active = 1 --and i.item_code = '457332' and i.item_code = r.item_code and r.urule_code = 'LCSPAINTSZ'
```

Comment: can you provide a printout what is `sheet['A2'].value`? better call it differently than SQL, it is usually reserved for constant. Also by saying SQL - do you mean there is some text in A2 column which qualifies as SQL? it is a bit confusing to understand what is inside the Excel file.

Comment: Sure SQL tab actaually contains SQL which i want to extract from the A2 value eg: select ip.item_code
, ip.gla_code_ar
,r.ruleit_text LCSPAINTSZ 
from item i
, itemplant ip
, ruleit r
where i.item_code = ip.item_code
and ip.plant_code = '14'
and i.item_active = 1
--and i.item_code = '457332'
and i.item_code = r.item_code
and r.urule_code = 'LCSPAINTSZ' i want to extact the sql from the A2 value and put it in the .sql file with the excel file name appended to it.

Comment: so A2  value is string and you just need to write it to file. fairly easy, will provide an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

```
# python 3.6 way is shorter
from pathlib import Path

# do you know the basename of the file you just read?
filename_xls = 'file123'

# is cell read as string?
cell_content_str = """select ip.item_code , ip.gla_code_ar ,r.ruleit_text LCSPAINTSZ 
from item i , itemplant ip , ruleit r where i.item_code = ip.item_code 
and ip.plant_code = '14' and i.item_active = 1 --and i.item_code = '457332' 
and i.item_code = r.item_code and r.urule_code = 'LCSPAINTSZ'"""

def make_sql_filename(basename: str):
    return f'{basename}.sql'

def write_to_sql_file(content: str, basename: str):
    Path(make_sql_filename(basename)).write_text(content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_to_sql_file(cell_content_str, filename_xls)
```

Generally it looks too simple to be an answer, perhaps I'm missing somehting from the question.